# Windows Universal App Open webbrowser with link

Tags: windows, universal

I am making an universal app and when i click a certain button, i need to open the webbrowser with a link. I got the link as a string in a variable but the windows 7 / 8 app ways such as "Proces" and Webbrowser objects give errors.

Answer (score 4):

In windows apps, you can't simply open other apps/programms.
The only posibility is to use the Launcher:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.de"));
```

The Launcher looks up the default program/app which is assosiated to the uri-scheme (in this case "http://" for webbrowsers) and forwards this call

Comment: use--  await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com")); and make scope async

Answer (score 0):

others then above you can go Package.app manifest change the start page to the URL that you want or another method by using web control set the source to the URL you needed.

Answer (score 0):

use scope async, it will open link to the mobile,PC default default browser for UWP

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.fmradiotune.blogspot.com"));
    }
```